# Whats the best way to audit changes on a particular form field?

Tags: php, asp.net, javascript, database, asp-classic

I need to add an entry into a database everytime a field changes in a form indicating the old value and the new value.

How would you go about this??

Would you...

1. Add a hidden field for every field and compare it to the new value on submit then add an audit entry if neccessary??
2. Do a select of the data to be inserted on post then compare each property and insert audit entry.
3. Any other ideas?

Cheers.

Comment: You've tagged this as ASP-Classic, PHP and ASP.NET.  Which one is it?

Comment: it's also tagged Javascript, which is a really bad idea. Don't use client-side for things like this.

Comment: server side javascript on classic asp.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to keep this in the app layer I would advice to use a model layer with properties per field to do the logging. All data access then goes trough this data model, giving you a hook to add functionality.

An [activerecord](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) based example (VBScript):

```
   class cSomeEntity
       public db ' link to a db wrapper
       private id, dirty, loaded ' varous flags 

       private sub class_initialize
         dirty = false
         loaded = false
       end sub

       private sub class_terminate
        if dirty then
            db.execute("update some_table set some_field=? where id=?", array(p_some_field, id))
        end if
       end sub

       public sub load_by_id(value)
         dim rs
         set rs = db.fetch_rs("select id, some_field from some_table where id=?", array(id))
         id = rs("id")
         p_some_field = rs("some_field")        
         loaded = true
       end sub

       private p_some_field
       public property get some_field
         some_field = p_some_field
       end property

       public property let some_field(value)
         if not loaded then err.raise 1, , "Entity not yet initialized, call .load_by_id() first!"
         if value <> p_some_field then
           dirty = true
           make_log_entry("some_value", p_some_field, value)           
           p_some_field = value      
         end if
       end property

       private sub make_log_entry(field, old_value, new_value)
         db.execute("insert into audit_log (table, field, old_value, new_value) values (?, ?, ?, ?)", _
           array("some_table", field, old_value, new_value))     
       end sub 
    end class
```

It might seem a bit bloated, but it is more flexible than a trigger based approach. For example you can easily implement range checks and such.

Secondly, when you need to write multiple entity classes you can push a lot of functionality in to a delegate class and use code template to write the property getter & setters.

Answer (score 0):

i think that first you can serialize the form to string ,
and compare with the latest string ,
to see if something change .
if 2 string equal you have nothing to do.

i supposed that all element in your form named by [] like :

form_name['first_name'] ....
form_name['last_name'] ....

if you using php you can do array_diff_assoc , to see what change.

all you need is save every time in db the latest form array  , save as string by serialized .

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use an update trigger in your database to do the comparing and auditing. (I don't have a code sample handy - sorry).

Comment: any other limits? can you use stored procedures? if you can i would go with option 2, inside a stored procedure (which would keep your app simple)

Comment: can you sp's but need to know the user who changed the value.

Comment: you could pass the user id to the SP as one of the variables?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what database you are using. You can try writing a procedure, which gets the current value and compares, store in the database. I suggest this as I think, this is more of a comparison to be done on the database side and not on the front-end.

Edit: Hey, if you use Oracle it is easy to write procedures. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Postgres or any other database that has functions you can easily write a function to do that for you that could be triggered whenever an `UPDATE` on a table is performed

For point 1, It's definitely not a good idea to include `hidden fields` in the form as someone could easily craft their own `POST` statement.

For point 2, This would work easily enough and is what I'd use if I couldn't write a function.

You'd wanna do something like this:

1. Validate that what they are submitting is valid
2. Select Information from the non-updated row
3. Store both the form data and the DB data in two arrays, for instance `$db_data` and `$form_data`
4. Get the differences using the function [`array_diff_assoc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php)

   ```
   $differences = array_diff_assoc($db_data,$form_data);
   ```

Keeping in mind that both the form and DB array need to have the same keys.